# No compileOnly configuration in the build.gradle but it is

Tags: gradle, intellij-plugin, grammar-kit

I have the following error message during the build, but no compileOnly dependency in my build.gradle. Why it's happens, and how to solve?
Regards

> Resolving dependency configuration 'compileOnly' is not allowed as it
> is defined as 'canBeResolved=false'. Instead, a resolvable
> ('canBeResolved=true') dependency configuration that extends
> 'compileOnly' should be resolved.

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        }

        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }

        repositories {
            flatDir {
                dirs 'jars'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}


plugins {
    id "org.jetbrains.intellij" version "1.10.1"
    id "org.jetbrains.grammarkit" version "2020.1"

}

configurations {
    configurations.implementation.setCanBeResolved(true)
}

group 'com.interfaced'
version '0.2.7'

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.intellij'

sourceSets {
    all {
        java.srcDirs += ['src/main/gen']
        kotlin.srcDirs += ['src/main/kotlin']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
    }
}


grammarKit {
    jflexRelease = '1.7.0-2'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://cache-redirector.jetbrains.com/intellij-dependencies"
    }
}

dependencies {
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib
    compileClasspath  group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', name: 'kotlin-stdlib', version: '1.7.22'

    compileClasspath  files('jars/grammar-kit.jar')
    compileClasspath  group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compileClasspath  "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7"

}

intellij {
    version '2022.3'
}

import org.jetbrains.grammarkit.tasks.GenerateLexer
import org.jetbrains.grammarkit.tasks.GenerateParser

def GENERATE_GROUP = 'Generate'

task generateLexer(type: GenerateLexer) {
    source = "src/main/grammar/BrightScript.flex"
    targetDir = "src/main/gen/com/interfaced/brs/lang/lexer"
    targetClass = "_BrsLexer"
    skeleton = "src/main/grammar/idea-flex.skeleton"
    purgeOldFiles = true

    description = 'Generate Lexer Java sources for BrightScript'
    group = GENERATE_GROUP
}

task generateParser(type: GenerateParser) {
    source = "src/main/grammar/BrightScript.bnf"
    targetRoot = 'src/main/gen'
    pathToParser = 'src/main/gen/com/interfaced/brs/lang/BrsParser.java'
    pathToPsiRoot = 'src/main/gen/com/interfaced/brs/lang/psi'
    purgeOldFiles = true

    description = 'Generate Parser Java sources for BrightScript'
    group = GENERATE_GROUP

    // patch up to date check
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "17"
}

compileKotlin.dependsOn(generateLexer, generateParser)
```

Comment: You don't need to apply plugins that are listed in the plugins block. This happens automatically unless you disable apply.

Comment: But how to fix my problem?

Comment: The only think I see immediately that is wrong is that your dependencies should be using the `implementation` configuration instead of `compileClasspath`.

Comment: Also, remove the Kotlin plugin from the buildscript block and apply it in the plugins block.

Comment: Another thing, you don't see to set those directories for the source sets. Those are the default values.

Comment: This is my new bild.gradle

Comment: This is my new bild.gradle
https://github.com/vladimirkozhaev/brainstorm-vkozhaev-intellij-plugin/blob/apply_stackowerflow/build.gradle

And following stacktrace
Failed to query the value of extension 'intellij' property 'version'.
      > The value for the 'intellij.version' property was not specified
How to fix it?

Comment: Looking at the documentation for the intellij plugin, my guess is because you are trying to call `version` as method instead of setting a value to it with =.

Comment: After setting the version
intellij {
    type="IC"
    version = '2022.3'
}
I have 
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.DefaultMultiCauseException: Could not resolve com.jetbrains.intellij.idea:ideaIC:2022.3.

Maybe I need to change my version value on the some way?

Comment: At this point, I am unsure.